# What does 「花に育てる編集」 mean?

Tags: grammar, particle-に, phrases

I encountered this line while reading a passage.
Context:

> 知名度の高い執筆者ばかり適当に揃えて一冊の雑誌をつくる編集は、たとえて言えば、インスタント食品をうまく使って食卓を賑わす料理人みたいなものだ。失敗の危険は少ないかもしれないが創る喜びは少ない。
>
> そこへゆくと、まだ固いつぼみを見つけ出して、これにあたたかい春の風を送り、**花に育てる編集**のしごとはそれ自体が一つの芸術である。そういうことの可能なエディターはそれほど多くいるとは考えられないが、優れた才能の開花のかげにはきわめてしばしばこういう創造的編集が存在するのではあるまいか。

I understand first sentence of second paragraph as

> If you go there, finding flowers that have not bloomed yet, tending them with warm spring air (so that they can grow into flowers) is also an art in itself.

I understand 「花に育てる」 as an attribute clause which describes 「編集」 but I don't understand why 「に」 is used here instead of 「を」. Does using 「に」 here add any nuance ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **まだ固いつぼみ**を見つけ出して、**これ**にあたたかい春の風を送り、花に育てる

The direct object of 育てる is left out. It's これ, i.e. まだ固いつぼみ, "firm buds".

It's 「（これ(=まだ固いつぼみ)**を**）花**に**育てる」, "bring up (firm buds) into flowers".

---

> そこへゆくと、［まだ固いつぼみを見つけ出して、これにあたたかい春の風を送り、花に育てる］編集のしごとはそれ自体が一つの芸術である。

Means something along the lines of...

In contrast, the work of editing [where you find firm buds, tend them with warm spring air, and raise them into flowers] is an art in itself.

<sub>The part in brackets is a relative clause that modifies 編集のしごと.</sub>

Comment: So, 「に」 here is used to show conversion of a flower bud into a flower. Thank you for the detailed explanation!